# iOS Swift - Custom Axis Labels -- Core Plot Bar Graph

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot, axes

**TL;DR Is there a way to set a custom axis label's tick location in Swift (using core-plot lib)?**

i want to set custom labels for an axis in a CPTXYGraph.  I have created the label and set it to the xAxis like so:

```
xAxis.axisLabels = NSSet(array: customLabels)
```

that part is fine.  What is NOT fine, is that I can't set the location or index of the label to match it up with the 'tick' on the xAxis.

in Objective C, you can set a property

```
label.tickLocation
```

but I can't find the corresponding property or any pertinent method in Swift.  I can't find any class references in Swift, either.  Is there a way to set the label's tick location in Swift?

Comment: why the down arrows?

Comment: The Swift API is the same as Objective-C, with the obvious differences in language syntax. Have you looked at the [online docs](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/index.html)?

Comment: yes, i've looked over that document.  i want a property called tickLocation but there is no such property in Swift.  i can't find any documentation for Swift that would suggest another way to get to this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no property called tickLocation because NSDecimal was done away with in Swift.  I had to extend CPTAxisLabel and create my own method setTickLocation.  Fun stuff

Comment: The code on the `release-2.0` branch on [Github](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) has some API changes that work better in Swift. It replaces all of the external `NSDecimal` properties and method parameters with ones that take `NSDecimalNumber` instances.